# Headless mode in chrome cant find elements on python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, headless

For some reason when I try to run a Headless Chrome it gives me a no such element error. edit: keep in mind that I using a proxy that automatically goes through a login page for an app before rendering cnn.com.

```
def start_test(proxyHostInput, port):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxyHostInput + port)
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1366x768")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=3129')
    chromeDriver = r"C:\Users\Surfcrew\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('https://www.cnn.com/')

    try:
        # insert username
        username = browser.find_element_by_id("login_username")
        username.send_keys("REDACTED")
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body[@class='login_body ']/div[@class='topdiv']/div[@id='bar']/span"
                                      "[@id='login_name']/form[@class='form saml']/input[@class='button']").click()
        time.sleep(3)
        password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body[@class='login_body ']/div[@class='topdiv']/div[@id='bar']"
                                                 "/span[@id='login_password']/form[@class='form password']"
                                                 "/div[@class='formdiv']"
                                                 "/input[@id='password']")

        # insert pass
        password.send_keys(readacted)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body[@class='login_body ']/div[@class='topdiv']/div[@id='bar']"
                                      "/span[@id='login_password']/form[@class='form password']"
                                      "/input[@id='password_submit']").click()
```

but I am still getting this error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"login_username"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Can somebody explain why or how to solve this?

Comment: Is it right URL?

Comment: yup the program run perfectly without the `headless` option

Comment: @KimKiamco I don't find any element on the webpage `https://edition.cnn.com/` matching with `find_element_by_id("login_username")`. Am I missing something?

Comment: ohh but heres the thing Im testing an app that isolates the cnn webpage in the cloud as a result the source page is different compared to the original one. I can assure you it runs without headless option

Comment: Tried using an user agent that doesn't identify as headless?

Comment: @misantroop yup tried that too and it works but as soon as i put the headless option it crashes :(

Comment: So combining for example '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36' and '--headless' does not find the element?

Comment: @misantroop my bad I tested a user agent that has a lower version haha but yea that fixed the problem .. Thanks!!!.. sorry only picked up programming 3 days ago =))

Comment: walang problema

Comment: @misantroop hey thanks for that didn't know chrome put headless in the user agent. how silly.